# How to parse response from Recurly ruby client

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to work with [Recurly](http://docs.recurly.com/client-libraries/ruby) ruby client gem but getting frustrated on how to pass its response.

I'm doing a simple call to get a list of all my current plans ie

```
  def plans
    @result_object = Recurly::Plan.all
  end
```

I believe its sending me a list of plans as an array as if I inspect the response I'm getting a bunch data ie. http://pastie.org/3086492

But if so how are you meant to parse the setup_fee_in_cents: when I am getting

```
setup_fee_in_cents: #<Recurly::Money USD: 0_00>
```

I have tried to convert the response to_hash but getting an error undefined method 'to_hash'

Has anyone used the recurly gem before or can shed some light on how I should parse the response.

Hope someone can advise.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used the gem before but it appears as though it's returning you an object of type `Recurly::Money`.  [I would try reading the documentation on the `Recurly::Money` class to get a better idea of how to use it](http://rubydoc.info/gems/recurly/2.0.9/Recurly/Money).

Answer (score 0):

`to_hash` works fine on `Recurly::Money` object. Try updating your gem. I am using recurly 2.0.9.

`r[0].unit_amount_in_cents.to_hash[:USD]` gave me the price in cents.